# Vmware client "vpxclient has stopped working"

Tags: vmware-player, vmware-server

So I closed the host using my client on my win 10 laptop, ever since I haven't been able to connect to host via the laptop but I can using my desktop.

I have tried a few things after searching on Google such as edit the clients config file on my laptop. But still playing up and it's really frustrating. Don't know if it is coincidence that client stopped working from the laptop since closing host.

Any ideas would be marvellous. I am stumped.

Comment: Are you able to provide any error messages?

Answer (score 0):

I was missing Tahoma fonts.  I copied Tahoma.ttf from another Windows 7 machine and installed the font on the laptop that was crashing.  All fixed.

Check out the latest log file in C:\Users\\AppData\Local\VMware\vpx.  Mine indicated:

System.ArgumentException: Font 'Tahoma' does not support style 'Regular'.
...
   at System.Drawing.Font..ctor(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)

--- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Sure enough, I was missing the Tahoma font.

Answer (score -1):

Try this fix as it helped me not to lose my head:

> [Posted on Monday 07/03/2016 by Victor](https://victorhomocea.wordpress.com/2016/03/07/vpxclient-has-stopped-working/)
>
> 1. Navigate to C:\Program Files (x86)\VMware\Infrastructure\Virtual Infrastructure Client\Launcher
> 2. Edit as Administrator VpxClient.exe.config
> 3. Add the following lines in a new line, prefferably after :
>
>    ```
>    <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy=”true”>
>    <supportedRuntime version=”v4.0″/>
>    </startup>
>    ```